# My hangman python code seems to be stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: python

In my hangman code I got the length of the letters and blank spaces to match up but for some reason i cannot get the letters to replace the spaces and its an infinite loop. I have no idea where I'm going wrong / what I'm missing.

```
from random import*

def main():
print
print "-----------------------------------"
print "H A N M G M A N: Tropical Fruit 1.0"
print "-----------------------------------"
print
wordList = ["pomegranate","mango","cassabanana","conkerberry","jujube"]
randomIdx = randrange(0, len(wordList))
secretWord = wordList[randomIdx]
print "(The secret word is", secretWord,")"
lettersGuessed = []
underscore = []
for i in range(len(secretWord)):
    underscore.append('_')
    newUnderscore = " ".join(underscore)
print newUnderscore
count = 6
while(True):
    guess = getNewLetter(lettersGuessed)
    if lettersGuessed == randomIdx:
        print "You guessed the letter! It is: ",ch2
        break

def getLetter():
   letter = True
   while (letter):
     ch = raw_input("Guess a letter: ")
     if len(ch) == 1:
       if ('a' <= ch) and (ch <= 'z'):
         return ch
       elif ('A' <= ch) and (ch <= 'Z'):
         return chr(ord(ch)-ord('A')+ord('a'))
       else:
         print ch,"is not a valid letter."
     else:
       print ch,"is not a single character."

def getNewLetter(oldChar):
letter = True
while (letter):
    ch = getLetter()
    if ch not in oldChar:
        oldChar.append(ch)
        return ch 
    else:
        print "You already guessed",ch,"!"


main()
```

EDIT: So i changed the while loop in the main function to this so the letter would append into blanks but still something is wrong.

```
while(True):
guess = getNewLetter(lettersGuessed)
if lettersGuessed == randomIdx:
        lettersGuessed.append(newUnderscore)
        return newUnderscore
        break
```

Comment: It's a little misleading to have `while(letter)` in your code (in both places) since what you actually mean is `while(True)`.

Comment: thanks i changed it to both of them being while(True)

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
if lettersGuessed == randomIdx:
```

never be true. lettersGuessed is an array of the letters that have been guessed so far (something like `['c', 'o', 'n']`. randomIdx is the index of the word that was chosen (something like `2`).

ETA: There are a few other problems- for example, if the line

```
print "You guessed the letter! It is: ",ch2
```

were executed, you'd find that `ch2` was never defined. Besides, you're not seeing if they guess the letter, you're seeing if they guess the word. Perhaps what you're looking for is something more like this:

```
        if set(secretWord).issubset(set(lettersGuessed)):
            print "You guessed the word!"
```

When this change is made, here is an example run of the program:

```
-----------------------------------
H A N M G M A N: Tropical Fruit 1.0
-----------------------------------

(The secret word is mango )
_ _ _ _ _
[]
Guess a letter: M
['m']
Guess a letter: A
['m', 'a']
Guess a letter: N
['m', 'a', 'n']
Guess a letter: G
['m', 'a', 'n', 'g']
Guess a letter: O
You guessed the word!
```

ETA: You can insert the line:

```
        print "".join([l if l in lettersGuessed else "_" for l in secretWord])
```

into the while loop. The program's behavior would then be like this:

```
-----------------------------------
H A N M G M A N: Tropical Fruit 1.0
-----------------------------------

(The secret word is jujube )
_ _ _ _ _ _
______
Guess a letter: J
j_j___
Guess a letter: U
juju__
Guess a letter: B
jujub_
Guess a letter: E
You guessed the word!
```

Comment: What if instead i wanted to have the blanks be replaced with the letter instead of it creating another list underneath the "guess a letter"